# SQOOP: export $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME error

Tags: sqoop

I encoutered this problem while trying to launch sqoop. I got an error:

```
gurung@ubuntu:~$ sqoop;
Error: /usr/local/sqoop/bin/../../hadoop-mapreduce does not exist!
Please set $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME to the root of your Hadoop MapReduce installation.
gurung@ubuntu:~$ export $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
bash: export: `=/usr/local/hadoop': not a valid identifier
```

Any advice and help would be appreciated!!
bj

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo. You don't have to add the `$` before the variable name when you use `export`.

```
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME` in your `.bashrc`.